# How to get info (number of fields, fields type) about result set that i get using C++ and ODBC driver for Oracle

Tags: c++, oracle, odbc

I can just get data using SQLExecDirect and SQLBindCol, but if i dont know how many fields and what type a query will return me? That is, how do I process the query like "SELECT * FROM X" ? I would be very grateful for any links or explanation.

Comment: So, no one will help me ? Or I asked an incorrect / stupid question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at SQLNumResultCols API to find the number of columns. Look at the SQLDescribeCol API to find details of the columns.

Comment: Then would you mind marking my answer as the answer - thanks.